# Rails 4 associations - modeling parties, invites, and users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm attempting to setup the associations for the following scenario  [(from The Odin Project):](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/associations?ref=lc-pb)

"You like hosting people for dinner so you want to build a dinner party invitation site. A user can create parties, invite people to a party, and accept an invitation to someone else's party."

I came up with the code below but have a few questions:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :parties, foreign_key: :host_id

        has_many :invitations_sent, class_name: "Invitation", foreign_key: :host_id
        has_many :invitations_rcvd, class_name: "Invitation", foreign_key: :guest_id

        has_many :guests, through: :invitations_sent
        has_many :hosts, through: :invitations_rcvd
    end

    class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :host, class_name: "User"

        belongs_to :guest, class_name: "User"
        belongs_to :party
    end

    class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :host, class_name: "User"
        has_many :invitations
    end
```

1. Is there a cleaner way to implement the above? It seems like the User model is doing a lot but I wonder if it's worth splitting it up into separate Guest and Host models, especially if they'll have the same attributes/columns anyways.
2. Is it possible to update the code above so that expressions like `User.first.parties.first.invitations.create(guest_id: 2)` auto-populates the host_id of the new invitation instance with `User.first`'s id?